# Is set in Uint8ClampedArray any faster than a for loop

Tags: javascript

for a Uint8ClampedArray (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray), is the following any faster than a for loop:

```
arr.set(arr.subarray(5,8),2);
```

vs

```
for(var i=5;i<=8;i++){
 arr[2 + i-5] = arr[i];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to know (especially for such small indices as you have, where the overhead of a method call is more significant) is to benchmark the two solutions against each other on your target platform.

In general, the builtin methods are supposed to be faster as they can use the underlying data structures more efficiently. At least as long as they are not required by the spec to consider lots of weird edge cases, and of course when their implementations is actually optimised.

Comment: loop turns out to be faster for small arrays. In big arrays, inbuilt method is faster

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow: So, just as expected :-)